# Maximal ideals of $F[x]/(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm trying to find all the maximal ideals of $F[x]/(x^2)$, where F is a field. I know that these are in bijective correspondence with the maximal ideals of $F[x]$ containing $(x^2)$, and the only maximal ideal of $F[x]$ containing $(x^2)$ is $(x)$ (since $F[x]$ is a PID and so all the maximal ideals all generated by irreducible monic polynomials in $F[x]$). Now I'm not able to understand how to take this ideal to an ideal in $F[x]/(x^2)$. More specifically, will the only maximal ideal in $F[x]/(x^2)$ be the image of $(x)$ under the canonical map $\phi: F[x] \rightarrow F[x]/(x^2)$? If yes, how do I find this image?

Comment: You have basically solved your problem -- the only maximal ideal in $F[x]/(x^2)$ is $xF[x]+(x^2)$. The canonical map $\phi\colon F[x]\to F[x]/(x^2)$ restricts to a linear isomorphism from $\{a+bx: a,b \in F\}$ to $F[x]/(x^2)$, and the image of the ideal $(x)=xF[x]$ is just $\{bx+(x^2): b\in F\}$.

Comment: The ring $R=F[x]/(x^2)$ has only three ideals $0$, $(\bar x)$, and $R$.

Comment: @krm2233 got it! In general, the image of an ideal J under the canonical map $R \rightarrow R/I$ need not be $J + I$, right? How do I find $\phi(J)$?

Comment: @krm2233 shouldn't the image of $(x)$ be $\{f(x)x + (x^2) + (x^2) | f(x) \in F[x]\}$?

Comment: @Math boi -- it is true that the image of $(x)$ is $f(x).x+(x^2)\mid f(x)\in F[x]\}$, but that is essentially just repeating the definition. Since any $g(x)\in F[x]$ can be written as $a+bx+x^2g_1(x)$ where $a,b \in F$ and $g_1(x)\in F[x]$, and then $g(x)+(x^2) = (a+bx)+(x^2)$. If $g(x) = x.f(x) \in (x)$ then $a=0$, and if $f(x) = c+dx+ x^2f_1(x)$, then  $xf(x)+(x^2) = cx +(x^2)$, hence the image of $(x)$ in $F[x]/(x^2)$ is $\{cx+(x^2): c\in F\}$.